# Comparing two arrays in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I know this has been asked before, and I know there are functions to make this easy in Perl.  But what I want is advice on my specific code.  I want to go through each line of text which I've read from a file, and compare it to the same line from another file, printing them if they are different.

I've tried as many variations of this as I could think of, and none work.  This specific code which I'm posting thinks every element in the array is different from the one in the other array.

```
use 5.18.2;
use strict;
use utf8;

printf "This program only compares two files.\n"
    . "Here are the differences between "
    . $ARGV[0] . " and " . $ARGV[1] . ":\n";

open FIRST_FH, '<', $ARGV[0];

chomp(my @file1 = <FIRST_FH>);

close FIRST_FH;
open SECOND_FH, '<', $ARGV[1];

chomp(my @file2 = <SECOND_FH>);

close SECOND_FH;
for(my $i=0; $i < scalar @file1; ++$i){
    my $string = $file2[$i];
    unless($_ =~ /$string/){
    print "Difference found: @file1[$i], @file2[$i]\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`use utf8;` just instructs the interpreter to read your source file as UTF-8. Use the `open` pragma to set the default IO layers to UTF-8 (or manually specify '<:encoding(UTF-8)' as the second argument to `open`).

Don't use `printf` when `print` will suffice (it usually does, due to interpolation). In this particular instance, I find a heredoc to be most readable.

It's inefficient to read both files into memory. Iterate over them lazily by taking one line at a time in a `while` loop.

Always check if `open` failed and include `$!` in the error message. Alternatively, `use autodie;`, which handles this for you. Also, use lexical filehandles; they'll automatically close when they go out of scope, and won't clash with other barewords (e.g. subroutines and built-ins).

Keeping in mind these suggestions, the new code would look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.18.2; # Implicitly loads strict
use warnings;
use open qw(:encoding(utf8) :std);

print <<"EOT";
This program only compares 2 files.
Here are the differences between 
$ARGV[0] and $ARGV[1]:
EOT

open(my $file1, '<', shift) or die $!;
open(my $file2, '<', shift) or die $!;

while (my $f1_line = <$file1>, my $f2_line = <$file2>)
{
    if ($f1_line ne $f2_line)
    {
        print $f1_line, $f2_line;
    }
}
```

But this is still a naive algorithm; if one file has a line removed, *all* subsequent lines will differ between files. To properly achieve a `diff`-like comparison, you'll need an implementation of an algorithm that finds the longest common subsequence. Consider using the CPAN module `Algorithm::Diff`.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you comparing using `$_`?  Which you haven't defined anywhere?

```
my $string = $file2[$i];
unless($_ =~ /$string/){
```

Simply compare the lines using `eq` or `ne`:

```
if ( $file1[$i] ne $file2[$i] ) {
```

However, I would recommend that you make a lot of stylistic changes to your script, starting with doing line by line processing instead of slurping in the files.  The following is how I would completely rewrite it:

```
use 5.18.2;
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use utf8;

my ( $file1, $file2 ) = @ARGV;

open my $fh1, '<', $file1;
open my $fh2, '<', $file2;

while ( !eof($fh1) && !eof($fh2) ) {
    chomp( my $line1 = <$fh1> );
    chomp( my $line2 = <$fh2> );
    if ( line1 ne $line2 ) {
        warn "Difference found on line $.:\n   $line1\n   $line2\n";
    }
}

warn "Still more data in $file1\n" if !eof $fh1;
warn "Still more data in $file2\n" if !eof $fh2;
```

Comment: I completely forgot about eq and ne, although I'd learned about them.  Thanks for the proper direction.